# Defining a vskip that possibly becomes vfill

Tags: plain-tex, vertical-spacing

I hope this is not a duplicate; I tried to search around and didn't find anything, but perhaps I used the wrong keywords. I'm using Plain TeX and have the following defined:

```
\newskip\hugeskipamount
\hugeskipamount=24pt plus 8pt minus 8pt
\def\hugeskip{\vskip\hugeskipamount}
```

This is all fine and well, however sometimes when I have

```
A
\hugeskip
B
```

and B starts a new page, the `vskip` disappears at the bottom of the page, and the page becomes all streched out, giving an underfull `vbox`. Is there a way to define `hugeskip` in such a way that if it turns up at the end of a page, it just functions like a `vfill`, i.e., there'll be a bit of a gap at the end of the page (which I find better than increased gaps between paragraphs). Thanks!

Comment: In addition to David Carlisle's excellent answer below, I figured out that you can also use `\raggedbottom` which also fixes other kinds of underfull `hbox`es by adding that extra space below. (But be careful of places you have put `\goodbreak`.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question would have been clearer with an example but if I understand correctly

```
\def\hugeskip{\vskip\hugeskipamount\filbreak}
```

`\filbreak` is  plain macro `\vfil\penalty-200\vfilneg` so normally it does nothing but if a page break happens at the penalty you get vfil at the bottom of the page, the `\vfilneg` is discarded before the next page starts.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! This worked for me